# Is is possible to have sounds play through headphones AND the phone itself?

Tags: notifications, ringtone

I have a Samsung S22 running Android 13. I use this with a bluetooth headset all day long, mostly for meetings and phone calls.

If I disconnect the headset from the phone when not in use, it's quite annoying to reconnect every time I want to use the headset, especially when in a hurry because I'm trying to answer a phone call. (There's also a few moments of latency before the connection goes through, and that's especially annoying when I can't hear the caller at all.)

But if I leave the phone and headset connected, and I put the headset down, then I don't hear the phone ring at all! (Or notifications.)

So what I would like is for ringtones, text tones, and notifications to play through the headset AND the phone speakers. Failing that, to play those through the phone, but have the phone call itself (and Zoom and everything else) play through the headset.

Can this be done?